# Nesting KMZ files

Tags: kml, google-earth, kmz

Is it possible to create one KMZ file that is composed of several smaller KMZ files?  I would prefer to not have to manually merge the actual KML entities, but I will if that's the only option.

Comment: What about bundling multiple KML files into one KMZ file?  Will GE load all of the KML files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A KMZ file can have any number of inner KML files (NOT KMZ files). But the first entry in the KMZ file must be the root KML file (typically named *doc.kml*), which may include network links with references to other KML or KMZ files. Several inner KML files, for example, could reference a shared style (in another KML file) via relative URLs.

The inner KML files can nest to any level of depth to other KML files so you can create a hierarchy of nested KML files.

KMZ files within KMZ files is not supported in Google Earth so that is not recommended. If you want a root KMZ file to reference other sub-KMZ files then the sub-KMZ files should not be sub-entries of the root KMZ file but located at the same relative context in the web server or file system.

Here is what a root KML file in a KMZ file would look like that includes at least two sub-KML files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <NetworkLink>
            <Link>
                <href>test1.kml</href>
            </Link>
        </NetworkLink>
        <NetworkLink>
            <Link>
                <href>test2.kml</href>
            </Link>
        </NetworkLink>
        ...
    </Document>
</kml>
```

You can set visibility tag to 0 or add [radio folders](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#listItemType) to selectively load inner KML files or add [Region](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#region) elements to load when given region is active. This would be needed to scale to lots of Features to achieve good performance.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#networklink