# Why is my NetworkLink not working inside a nested KMZ?

Tags: kml, google-earth, kmz

My problem is that I want to have a kmz file (nest1.kmz) nested within another kmz file (root.kmz) and also reference another nested .kml file (nest2.kml).

When I try to achieve this the network link that references the kml file does not load. 
[image]

The top answer for [Nesting KMZ files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109555/nesting-kmz-files/12897689#12897689) makes it seem like it should hopefully be possible, so am I doing something wrong here?

```
root.kmz    >root.kml
            >[nest1]    >
                        >nest1.kmz  >
                                    >nest1.kml
                                    >[nest2]    >
                                                >nest2.kml
```

The code for the 3 files is as follows:

**root.kml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <name>root.kmz</name>
        <NetworkLink>
            <name>nest1.kmz</name>
            <Link>
                <href>nest1/nest1.kmz</href>
            </Link>
        </NetworkLink>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

**nest1.kml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <name>nest1.kmz</name>
        <NetworkLink>
            <name>nest2.kml</name>
            <Link>
                <href>nest2/nest2.kml</href>
            </Link>
        </NetworkLink>
            <Placemark>
                <Point>
                    <coordinates>175.589370309749,-39.5968230904137,0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

**nest2.kml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
        <name>nest2.kml</name>
        <Placemark>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>176.589370309749,-39.5968230904137,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: I've amended the answer in Nesting KMZ files. KML 2.2 spec provides little guidance on KMZ files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a root KMZ file to reference other sub-KMZ files then the sub-KMZ files should not be sub-entries of the root KMZ file but located at the same relative context in the web server or file system.

Google Earth supports a large number of nested KML files within a KMZ file but does **NOT** support nested KMZ files within a parent KMZ file. Either layout the content as file structure where 1) all sub-kml files are within a single root.kmz file, or 2) sub-kmz files are co-located with the root kml or kmz file.

The file system or web server would have the following structures:

Structure 1:

```
root.kmz
  nest1/nested1.kml
  nest2/nested2.kml
```

Structure 2:

```
root.kmz
nest1/nested1.kmz
nest2/nested2.kmz
```

root.kmz can refer to nest1/nested1.kmz and nested1.kmz can then reference nested2.kmz.

Google Earth also supports sub-file references within a KMZ file so root.kmz could have a direct reference to nest2/nest2.kml if it is contained within nested1.kmz. That practice is not recommended since it may not be supported in applications other than Google Earth.

```
 <Link>
     <href>nested1.kmz/nest2/nested2.kml</href>
 </Link>
```